# iPhone: SIGSEGV occurs seemingly randomly (ViewDidLoad, setFont, etc.) on device, never in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

First, thanks in advance for taking the time to read through this.  I have been searching for an answer to this issue for a few days but I cannot seem to find what I am looking for.  I know that SIGSEGV errors (or EXEC_BAD_ACCESS faults) are usually caused by memory management issues but after hours of looking at the code, I can't seem to find an error.  The static analyzer hasn't found anything either.

As the title says, this error only occurs on the device (never in the simulator) and doesn't happen every time the given view loads.  Obviously this means that I can't use NSZombie to debug what is going wrong.

Let's start with the crash dump log:

```
0 myApp 0x00036659 +[TFCrashHandler backtrace] + 428
1 myApp 0x00036a6f TFSignalHandler + 54
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f48539 _sigtramp + 48
3 UIKit 0x365701df -[UIView(Rendering) setNeedsDisplay] + 86
4 UIKit 0x36598269 -[UILabel setFont:] + 232
5 myApp 0x000190eb +[BruUISettings applyLabelDetailStyle:] (BruUISettings.m:130)
6 myApp 0x0001aa57 -[ActiveChallengeViewController viewDidLoad] (ActiveChallengeViewController.m:115)
7 UIKit 0x365a57ff -[UIViewController view] + 166
8 UIKit 0x365b1c39 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 24
9 UIKit 0x365b1aa9 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 36
10 UIKit 0x365b198f -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 34
11 UIKit 0x365b115b -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 318
12 UIKit 0x365b0f53 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 250
13 UIKit 0x365a5673 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 806
14 UIKit 0x365a5349 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 36
15 myApp 0x00015dc7 -[ChallengesHomeViewController tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:] (ChallengesHomeViewController.m:325)
16 UIKit 0x3661f565 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 944
17 UIKit 0x36697ce7 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 158
18 Foundation 0x31f7a943 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 414
19 CoreFoundation 0x34ab1a63 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14
20 CoreFoundation 0x34ab16c9 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 364
21 CoreFoundation 0x34ab029f __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
22 CoreFoundation 0x34a334dd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 300
23 CoreFoundation 0x34a333a5 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
24 GraphicsServices 0x351a7fed GSEventRunModal + 156
25 UIKit 0x3659a743 UIApplicationMain + 1090
26 myApp 0x000026c5 main (main.m:13)
27 myApp 0x0000265c start + 52
```

Note, I am using TestFlight from testflightapp.com and it is there exception handler at the top of the stack.

Here is the code that is creating and pushing the view controller in question:

```
CDAcceptedChallenge *challengeAtIndex = [self.activeChallenges objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
ActiveChallengeViewController *view = [[ActiveChallengeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ActiveChallengeViewController" 
                                                                                      bundle:nil 
                                                                             activeChallenge:challengeAtIndex];
view.leaveChallengeTarget = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:view animated:YES];
[view release];
```

This code is running inside of a didSelectRowAtIndex method, if that matters at all.  This view controller has a bunch of member variables and IBOutlets which reference objects in the nib but here are the ones that correlate to the object mentioned in this error:

in .h:

```
UILabel *helpLabel;
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *helpLabel;
```

in .m:

```
@synthesize helpLabel;
```

I am positive that helpLabel is bound to the correct object in the nib because it does get the correct styling when this doesn't blow up. Next, here is the init method for this view controller:

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

if (self) 
{
    self.activeChallenge = inActiveChallenge;
}
return self;
```

Here is the viewDidLoad method where we will sometimes see the crash (bolded).  Note, there is a lot going on here but nothing touches the self.helpLabel which is what eventually triggers the crash.

```
[super viewDidLoad];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:FALSE];
self.navigationItem.title = @"Details";

// overlay disclosure creation
self.overlayDisclosure = [CustomColoredDisclosureIndicator accessoryWithColor:self.challengeNameLabel.textColor];
self.overlayDisclosure.highlightedColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.overlayDisclosure addTarget:self action:@selector(overlayViewButtonClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:self.overlayDisclosure];

[[BruNotificationManager instance] registerForTabUpdated:[[[BruCallback alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                                 andCallback:@selector(tabUpdated:)] autorelease]];
[[BruNotificationManager instance] registerForActiveChallengesUpdated:[BruCallback buildFromObject:self 
                                                                                       andCallback:@selector(challengesUpdatedLocally)]];
[[BruNotificationManager instance] registerForEarnedRewardsUpdated:[BruCallback buildFromObject:self 
                                                                                    andCallback:@selector(rewardsUpdatedLocally:)]];

[super refreshEarnedRewardsForChallenge:self.activeChallenge.challenge.identifier];
[super refreshTabForChallenge:self.activeChallenge.challenge.identifier];

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd 
                                                                           target:self 
                                                                           action:@selector(addBeer)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
[addButton release];

// Request that the object download its image
BruCallback *imageCallback = [BruCallback buildFromObject:self andCallback:@selector(imageRequestCompleted:withData:)];
self.challengeImageView.image = [self.activeChallenge.challenge retrieveImage:self.bruConnection withCallback:imageCallback];

// Create our help label
**[BruUISettings applyLabelDetailStyle:self.helpLabel];**
self.helpLabel.textColor = AccentSecondaryColor;

self.overlayView.alpha = [BruUISettings standardOverlayViewAlpha];

[BruUISettings applyTableStyle:self.rewardsTable];
[BruUISettings applyScrollViewStyle:self.scrollView];

self.needToUpdateTab = YES;
self.needToUpdateRewards = YES;
self.needToUpdateChallenge = NO;
```

Here is a trimmed down version of the viewDidUnload method, though I don't see why it would matter in this case:

```
...
self.helpLabel = nil;
...

[super viewDidUnload];
```

Finally, my [BruUISettings applyLabelDetailStyle] is a method that applies a centralized style to my label.  There are a bunch of places in my code that use this function so that I can change all of the styles for those labels by just changing the one function.

```
+ (void) applyLabelDetailStyle:(UILabel *)inLabel
{
    inLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:12.0];
    inLabel.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    inLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Any thoughts as to what could be happening here would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks again.

Comment: Could the issue be that you're getting lots of memory warnings (hence deallocations of your `view`) on your device, but not in the simulator?

Try setting of a few memory warnings in the Simulator to see if you're getting the issues there too.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Kristofer.  I have played around with simulating memory warnings in the simulator but it hasn't produced this error.  I would agree this is likely related to memory warnings but I don't understand how they could affect me in ViewDidLoad.  It seems that the label in question would be guaranteed to be in memory, regardless of memory warnings, in ViewDidLoad.  Is this not a safe assumption?

Comment: If this view isn't in the foreground and you're receiving a memory warning, it might be disposed of and recreated the next time the view's displayed (and loaded). Or does the error always occur when this particular view is displayed?

As you probably know, you should always be sure to balance any actions in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload`, or you might end up in a corrupted state.

Comment: ... but if you're only getting the error in `viewDidLoad` (and it's never invoked from somewhere else), if might not be the issue. But that'd be the first place I'd check.

Comment: Also, you're certain that the `textLabel` isn't released somewhere else in your code? I guess you could `retain` it in `applyLabelDetailStyle:` while you're doing your magic on it (although that is unlikely to help, since it wouldn't be displayed anywhere if it gets deallocated).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I found that this was actually due to a memory corruption being caused by the QSStrings library which I was using to generate base64 encoded strings.  The crashes seemed to happen randomly but only after this library was invoked.  When I switched to a different MD5 library, the issue went away.  If you are using this library, I would suggest finding a new one to do base64 encoding.  I moved to the one found here: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BaseSixtyFour

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same problem with the same library. I just wish I had found this post sooner, that was a hard debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem happens because you have something wrong in your view that owns your label (view of your ActiveChallengeViewController).

When you set the font of your label, that invokes the setNeedsDisplay of your parent view and because something is wrong, setNeedsDisplay crashs.

Your line :

```
self.challengeImageView.image = [self.activeChallenge.challenge retrieveImage:self.bruConnection withCallback:imageCallback];
```

Is it a synchronous connection to retrieve the image ?

Maybe the problem happen here when sometimes the image isn't retrieved from your connection and so the image property of your image view is bad.

But i am not sure because setNeedsDisplay doesn't directly invoke the redraw of the view so i don't know if the debugger catches the error just the after setNeedsDisplay call.

Edit :

I think this answer is bad, if image is not ok, the crash must happen when the imageView image property retains the image but i let the answer in the case of it could help you to point to the real problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info Johnmph.  One question, is the setNeedsDisplay call targeting the parent view in which the label lives or is it targeting the label itself?  I had assumed it was the label, but if it is the view then that likely would indicate that something is wrong with the view and not the label.

Comment: Normally, the setNeedsDisplay call must be in the label and not the parent view but i am not sure, i don't know how it's processed internally. Try to comment out self.challengeImageView.image = ... line and test if crash happen again